# How to make Chrome reload all JS and CSS file of a page?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

It is known that using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> can be used to force chrome browser to reload the page instead of reading from cache. However, while the images are reloaded, the JS and CSS files are not loaded. Currently I have to test my page on incognito mode, close and reopen the incognito tab so as to make sure the page is not using the cached JS and CSS files.

Is there any settings or hotkey I can do this in normal mode? It is really tiring to reopen the windows every time I need to test the changes in CSS or JS files.

Answer (score 27):

If you press 'F12' to open Chrome Dev Tools and select the network tab, you have the option to disable caching.

This only works with the Dev Tools Panel is open.

[image: Devtools Cache]

Comment: This worked for me.  Not sure why it hasn't been accepted as the answer.

Comment: I'm having a weird issue with chrome caching css even with this ticked, any ideas?

Comment: Is there a way to only disable caching on resources that aren't fetched over the internet? I'm using cdn for some libraries, and my internet connection is pretty slow...

Comment: Is there a way to disable cache for specific file types? e.g. Disable cache for .css and .js but allow cache for everything else.

Comment: I also have the problem that CSS and JS files still get cached although the dev window is open and "Disable cache" is ticked.

Comment: This is the first time I've ever heard of this option, and I've been dealing with this refresh issue for years.  Thank you!  FYI to others...you have to widen the Dev Tools frame enough to see this option.

Answer (score 12):

There are a couple of ways to Hard reload a website in chrome. All of them require us to open chrome *Developer tools.*

### Through short cut key combination

1. Make sure that chrome *Developer Tools* window is opened (by pressing F12)
2. Press *Ctrl + Shift + R*

### By setting property in *Network* tab

1. Make sure that chrome *Developer Tools* window is opened (by pressing F12)
2. Head over to *Network* tab
3. Tick *Disable cache* checkbox

### By long pressing *Reload* button

1. Make sure that chrome *Developer Tools* window is opened (by pressing F12)
2. Point to "Refresh button" in top left and long press left mouse button
3. A dropdown will then appear where we will get different options as shown in this image:

[image: How to make Chrome reload all JS and CSS file of a page?]

Answer (score 3):

Doing a hard reload should also do the trick as well. The answer above didn't always work for me, so doing the hard reload made it work for me.

[See how to here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD7TZ.png)

Comment: I forgot to mention that you have the dev tools open in chrome to be able to press and hold down the refresh button for those options

Answer (score 0):

Beware if you are using Chromium Embedded Framework as your http server. For me, when I run on Windows, CEF does not appear to do any caching on the server end (so devtools disable cache works for me). But when I run on Macintosh, no matter what I do on the client side (reload page, devtools disable cache), it serves the same file until I restart the CEF server. This is probably because I have something configured differently with CEF on the Macintosh side, but I don't remember making such changes.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down Ctrl and click the Reload button. Or, Hold down Ctrl and press F5. just open the Chrome Dev Tools by pressing F12. Once the chrome dev tools are open, just right click on the refresh button and a menu will drop down.

Answer (score -2):

You should try Ctrl+R or Ctrl+F5, or Go to Network Conditions tab in DevTools (Shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+I) and tick Disable Cache....